# Keep track of staking award token

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, testing

I'm building a smart contract where users can stake the native token and earn the same token as a reward. For example, users stake dai and earn back dai as a reward as well. I have made almost most of the contract but what I'm having an issue with is keeping track of the pool's balance. let's say I allocate 1000 dai to the farm for reward. how would i keep track of this balance? The reason to track is to withdraw by owner if no user staking.

```
contract BankContract {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    string public name = "Token farm";
    
    uint256 private totalFarmSupply;    //=1000000000000000000000; //1000 token for the pool
    IERC20 public ATRAC;
    address private owner;
    
    address[] public stakers;
    mapping(address => uint256) public stakingBalance;
    mapping(address => uint256) public rewardBalance;
    mapping(address => bool) hasStaked;
    mapping(address => bool) isStaking;
    uint constant duration = 1 days;
    uint private end;
    uint private balance;
    uint private totalRewardBalance;

    event Stake(address indexed from, uint256 amount);
    event UnStake(address indexed from, uint256 amount);
    
    constructor(IERC20 _ATRAC, uint256 _totalFarmSupply) {
        ATRAC =_ATRAC;
        owner = msg.sender;
        totalFarmSupply =  _totalFarmSupply;
        end = block.timestamp + duration;
    }
    
    modifier onlyOwner {
      require(msg.sender == owner);
      _;
    }
 function withdrawReward() public onlyOwner {
    require (msg.sender==address(0) && stakers.length==0);
    for (uint256 i=0; i<=stakers.length; i++){
        totalRewardBalance += rewardBalance[stakers[i]];
    }
    uint256 leftToken = (totalFarmSupply.sub(totalRewardBalance));
    if(totalFarmSupply>0){
        ATRAC.transfer(msg.sender, leftToken);
    }
}
```

Also, how do I assign TotalFarmsupply in js for testing.

would it be :

```
const supply = BankContract.totalFarmSupply;
```

is this correct?